# BIRT -line spacing in report design

Tags: birt

I wonder how to define the line spacing in a multi-line lable or text item for pdf output. While increasing the line height within a style works fine, decreasing the height to reduce line spacing doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to reduce the line pitch?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try removing top and bottom padding. I don't know about labels and text items, and maybe it's not the same, but I had a similar problem in a table with 8pt font in the details. It would look fine in HTML, but in PDF the space between the lines would be huge.

A good trick is to set background colors on the item and the surrounding cell and whatever other elements you have and you'll be able to see which element steals the space.

Then tweak the paddings, line height and font size to reduce the extra space as much as possible. Use the 'Advanced' properties panel (or preferably stylesheets), as line height is not available in 'General' for some elements.

I managed to get my table looking great doing this if I removed ALL top and bottom padding (from row, cell and data element), used a row line height of 10pt and a font size of 8pt.
There seems to be a bug that causes the actual text inside the data element to be somehow padded at the top no matter what in PDF. If you color the data element background and then select the text in the report, you'll see that the text is set too low on the element, overflowing a little at the bottom. Thats the reason 8pt font and 8pt line height wouldn't work for me, it would cut off the bottom of the text.